# Mapping SIC to FamaFrench Industry Classification

Tags: r, regex, sqldf

I am working on a project where I have to map firms that have an SIC industry classification to the corresponding Fama-French industry classification. I have found that Ian Gow has gracefully created the script to do this. The script is available from the following url: https://iangow.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/getting-fama-french-industry-data-into-r/

However, there is a glitch in the script or in the data set and for some reason, it does not work with “Siccodes30.txt”. More specifically, it does not produce the correct result (mapping) for lines related to “6726-6726 Unit inv trusts, closed-end” from the “Siccodes30.txt”. I have been trying to figure out the source of the problem, but I have not been successful.

In the post below, I have included the original script (there is some room to make it more efficient) and I have added a few lines at the end to make it work with an online example.

Original Script (I have removed comments to makes the post shorter). Again, this is not my script (the original script is in https://iangow.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/getting-fama-french-industry-data-into-r/

```
url4FF <- paste("http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu",
             "pages/faculty/ken.french/ftp",
             "Industry_Definitions.zip", sep="/")
f <- tempfile()
download.file(url4FF, f)
fileList <- unzip(f,list=TRUE)
trim <- function(string) {
ifelse(grepl("^\\s*$", string, perl=TRUE),"",
       gsub("^\\s*(.*?)\\s*$","\\1",string,perl=TRUE))
}
extract_ff_ind_data <- function (file) {
ff_ind <- as.vector(read.delim(unzip(f, files=file), header=FALSE, 
                           stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
ind_num <- trim(substr(ff_ind[,1],1,10))
for (i in 2:length(ind_num)) {
    if (ind_num[i]=="") ind_num[i] <- ind_num[i-1]
}
sic_detail <- trim(substr(ff_ind[,1],11,100))
is.desc <- grepl("^\\D",sic_detail,perl=TRUE)
regex.ind <- "^(\\d+)\\s+(\\w+).*$"
ind_num <- gsub(regex.ind,"\\1",ind_num,perl=TRUE)
ind_abbrev <- gsub(regex.ind,"\\2",ind_num[is.desc],perl=TRUE)
ind_list <- data.frame(ind_num=ind_num[is.desc],ind_abbrev,
                       ind_desc=sic_detail[is.desc])

regex.sic <- "^(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\s*(.*)$"
ind_num <- ind_num[!is.desc]
sic_detail <- sic_detail[!is.desc]
sic_low  <- as.integer(gsub(regex.sic,"\\1",sic_detail,perl=TRUE))
sic_high <- as.integer(gsub(regex.sic,"\\2",sic_detail,perl=TRUE))
sic_desc <- gsub(regex.sic,"\\3",sic_detail,perl=TRUE)
sic_list <- data.frame(ind_num, sic_low, sic_high, sic_desc)

return(merge(ind_list,sic_list,by="ind_num",all=TRUE))
}

FFID_30 <- extract_ff_ind_data("Siccodes30.txt")
```

I have added the following lines to allow testing the script:

```
library(gsheet)
url <-"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QRv8YmJv0pdhIVmkXMQC7GQuvXV21Kyjl9pVZsSPEAk/gid=1758600626"
companiesSIC <- read.csv(text=gsheet2text(url, format='csv'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(companiesSIC)

library(sqldf)
companiesFFID_30 <- sqldf("SELECT a.gvkey, a.SIC, b.ind_desc AS FF30, 
    b.ind_num as FFIndNUm30
FROM companiesSIC AS a
  LEFT JOIN FFID_30 AS b
  ON a.sic BETWEEN b.sic_low AND b.sic_high")
companiesFFID_30
```

Results on rows 141 and 142 are wrong. Instead of an industry number the provide a string.

Thanks

PS As I said there is room to make the script shorter (e.g., you don't need to create a separate function to remove white space, you can use trimws) but to give credit to the original author, I kept the script in its original form. However, if someone can solve the problem should also try to update the rest of the script too.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the script. The problem is in the formatting of the two lines (141 and 142) of the txt file.

I opened the text file with a text editor, deleted and re-typed the content of these two lines. When I re-run the R script the problem was gone.